# How can I plot the mean of sliding groups of data in R?

Tags: r, statistics, grouping, plot, frequency-distribution

I have a frequency distribution I am trying to plot in R. The dataset is quite noisy however and results in an untidy plot.

I would like to take the mean of 10 unit sliding windows and plot that data instead. Hopefully this will clean up the plot, by reducing the number of data points?

I have tried scatter.smooth() and loess(), but these don't do what I want. I could code this myself, but wondered if anyone was aware of a function that might save the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this whilst continuing my search on Google - This appears to solve my problem :D

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/mean-of-a-sliding-window-in-r

**Edit:**

I'm using the following

```
library(zoo)
quartz()
plot(rollmean(freq_dist, 10))
```

Works like a dream :-D

I did an `install.packages("zoo", dependencies=TRUE)` in order to get the zoo library into R!